# confusion about printf() in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to hexdump a file with following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 16

void pre_process(char buffer[],int len);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc == 2){
        char *file = argv[1];
        FILE *input = fopen(file,"r");
        char buffer[SIZE];
        char *tmp = malloc(4);
        while(!feof(input)){ 
            printf("%06X  ",ftell(input)); /*print file pos*/
            fread(buffer,1,SIZE,input); /*read 16 bytes with buffer*/
           
            for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i += 4){ /*print each 4 bytes with hex in buffer*/
                memcpy(tmp,buffer+i,4);
                printf("%08X  ",tmp);
            }
            printf("*");
            pre_process(buffer,SIZE); /*print origin plain-text in buffer. subsitute unprint char with '*' */
            printf("%s",buffer);
            printf("*\n");
        }
        free(tmp);
        fclose(input);
   }
}

void pre_process(char buffer[],int len){
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(isblank(buffer[i]) || !isprint(buffer[i]))
            buffer[i] = '*';
    }
}
```

reading a slice from lord of ring,result as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VliYZ.png)

so, why the hex code are all the same ? It looks like something wrong with `printf("%08X  ",tmp);`
thx for your help.

Comment: Enable warnings.  You're using `%08X`, which expects an `unsigned int`, to print `tmp`, which is a pointer (and quite likely a different size).  So you're just printing some portion of the address over and over, which doesn't change.  Enable warnings, and fix them all.

Answer (score 3):

The answer lies here:

```
memcpy(tmp,buffer+i,4);
printf("%08X  ",tmp);
```

`memcpy` as you might already be aware, copies `4` bytes from `buffer+i` to where `tmp` is pointing to.

Even though this is done in a loop, `tmp` continues to hold the address of a specific location, which is never changed. The contents at that address/location in memory are updated with every `memcpy()` call.

In a nutshell, the house remains there only, hence the address remains the same but people change places, new people arrive as older ones are wiped out!

Also, there is plenty to improve/fix here. I recommend starting with enabling warnings by `-Wall` option with your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

`tmp` stores the *address* of a buffer; that address never changes.  What you want to print is the contents of the buffer that `tmp` *points to*.  In this case, `tmp` point to a buffer of 4 `char`s; if you write

```
printf( "%08X ", *tmp );
```

you’ll only print the value of the first element - since `tmp` has type `char *`, the expression `*tmp` has type `char` and is equivalent to writing `tmp[0]`.

To treat what’s in those bytes as an `unsigned int` (which is what the `%X` conversion specifier expects), you need to *cast* the pointer to the correct type before dereferencing it:

```
printf( "%08X ", *(unsigned int *) tmp );
```

We first have to cast `tmp` from `char *` to `unsigned int *`, then dereference the result to get the `unsigned int` equivalent of those four bytes.

This assumes `sizeof (unsigned int) == 4` on your system - to be safe, you should write your `malloc` call as

```
char *tmp = malloc( sizeof (unsigned int) );
```

and

```
for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i += sizeof (unsigned int) )
{
  memcpy( tmp, buffer + i, sizeof (unsigned int) );
  ...
}
```

instead.

You should not use `feof` as your loop condition - it won’t return true until after you try to read past the end of the file, so your loop will execute once too often.  You’ll want to look at the return value of `fread` to determine whether you’ve reached the end of the file.